# Eclipse Subversive shows committed files as incoming changes

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Every time I commit changes to SVN repository, after commit they show up in Synchronise view in Eclipse as incoming changes. Of course, doubleclicking them shows no differences (as they have just been committed), but only after a while and after a new synchronize action they don't appear as incoming changes anymore.

Any idea on what's causing this issue?

Comment: Have you made an update of your whole working copy in between?

Comment: No, the workflow is as follows (i.e. ona  single file). I make same changes on a file (on the latest trunk version from SVN), synchronize, it shows as 1 outgoing file. I commit it from synchronize view, and literally after it is committed, it is flagged as 1 incoming file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a system error with our SVN server.